# How to pass value

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-kotlin

How to get value `time` from this code

```
val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.name
TrueTimeRx.build()

    .initializeRx("time.google.com")

    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

    .subscribe({ time ->
        Log.v(TAG, "TrueTime was initialized and we have a time: $time") },
        { throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace() }

    )
```

and put it in this code

```
helloWorld=findViewById(R.id.helloWorld)

val newTime=getString(R.string.hello, time)
helloWorld.text=newTime
```

how to take `time` from the first part of the code and to put it in the second

code above is in `onCreate()`

and if it's important i have this

```
internal lateinit var helloWorld: TextView
```

Answer (score 1):

The value will be available in the subscriber block:

```
TrueTimeRx.build()
    .initializeRx("time.google.com")
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({ time ->
      Log.v(TAG, "TrueTime was initialized and we have a time: $time")
      val newTime = getString(R.string.hello, time)
      helloWorld.text = newTime
    }, { throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace() }
    )
```

Note that you have to `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` to be able to modify View contents inside the block.